# Should I use GenSeq by default?

Tags: scala, collections

Is it the best practice to use GenSeq as a "default" collection type? It seems to be the most generic collection interface. However I don't see it widely used in code examples (the more specific Seq is used instead).

Comment: I would say, it *really depends* and I think you may use it if you want your code to work with both sequential and parallel collections.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The most generic collection types that should appear in APIs are:

- `Seq` — sequential collection
- `Set` — mathematical sets (no duplicated values)
- `Map` — associations / associative sets (conceptually the same as discrete `PartialFunction`s)

The only abstractions that are neutral to the distinction between the foregoing are `Traversable` and `Iterable`. (E.g. `Map[K, V]` is both `Iterable[(K, V)]` and `Traversable[(K, V)]`.

If all that matters for an actual parameter is that its elements may be examined in some (unspecified) order, then `Traversable` captures that characteristic.

Class or trait names that include "Like" or "Once" or "Gen" are part of the internal magic that makes Scala collections exhibit the "principle of least surprise" (chief among them being the property that invoking a HOF upon them such as `map` or `filter` yields a result with a matching concrete type as that of the collection upon which that HOF was invoked).

Comment: According to https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/architecture.html you should use GenSeq if you want to work with parallel and non-parallel sequences (Making it more generic)

Answer (score 4):

Note you don't need `GenSeq` anymore with [Scala 2.13 (June 2019)](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0), considering Parallel collections are now a separate module: [`scala/scala-parallel-collections`](https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections)

So no more `GenSeq` (or any `Genxxx`)

> To depend on scala-parallel-collections in sbt, add this to your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies +=
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "0.2.0"
```

> In your code, adding this import:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Seq is used for non parallel (Sequential) collections of sequences.

GenSeq is the common trait beteen parallel and normal sequences.

ParSeq is the non-sequential sequence (Pun intended), which is implemented using parallelism.

There are a couple methods missing from GenSeq (Like contains) but in my experience they are trivially implemented by hand (You can try looking at the implementations in Seq).

Source: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/architecture.html

Another good page about scala collections (Non-parallel ones): https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html